# How can we activate a WPF trigger in XAML when a drag operation is occurring?

Tags: wpf, triggers, drag-and-drop

We're looking for a way to base a WPF trigger in XAML on whether or not we're in a drag-drop operation.  Depending on if we are or not, we want different hovering behaviors which is why this is needed.

The only way I can think of is to handle the drag start and end events and manually track the state, but that requires a code-behind, not pure XAML.  Plus it seems like complete overkill, especially since we'd have to do it on every potential drop target which is a real pain.

So is there an easy way to say 'Hey... I'm in a drag-drop operation so make this trigger active' or am I out of luck here?

---

### Update

To clarify what we are trying to do, currently in pure XAML, you can create a style, then set a style trigger to examine the IsMouseOver property to say, draw a background highlight.  Well, we want to do this, but we want to say if 'IsMouseOver' is true **and** if IsDragging = true then apply this trigger.

Comment: have you found anything yet? I am trying to find the answer on how to do the drag and drop behaviour using pure xaml on the view as well :(

Comment: @Anon, I'm pretty sure that functionality isn't built into XAML. You'll need to at least implement a handler for the `Drop` event. It's available on `UIElement`.

Comment: In my case, I'm not looking for the drop event.  I'm trying to apply a style.  I've clarified above.

Comment: Do you actually have a property IsDragging on the Object?

Answer (score 2):

I've just had this problem, my solution consists of using an attached property that supplies the missing `IsDragging`:

1. Define the attached Property

   ```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDraggingProperty =
       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
       (
           "IsDragging",
           typeof(bool),
           typeof(ClassContainingThisProperty),
           new UIPropertyMetadata(false)
       );

   public static bool GetIsDragging(DependencyObject source)
   {
       return (bool)source.GetValue(IsDraggingProperty);
   }

   public static void SetIsDragging(DependencyObject target, bool value)
   {
       target.SetValue(IsDraggingProperty, value);
   }
   ```
2. Create this extension methods to help you set the Property

   ```
   public static TParent FindParent<TParent>(this DependencyObject child) where TParent : DependencyObject
   {
       DependencyObject current = child;
       while(current != null && !(current is TParent))
       {
           current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
       }
       return current as TParent;
   }

   public static void SetParentValue<TParent>(this DependencyObject child, DependencyProperty property, object value) where TParent : DependencyObject
   {
       TParent parent = child.FindParent<TParent>();
       if(parent != null)
       {
           parent.SetValue(property, value);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Handle DragDrop events according to the Control used (e.g. ListView), to set the attached property on the elements.

   ```
   private void OnDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
       DependencyObject source = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
       if (source != null)
       {
           source.SetParentValue<ListViewItem>(ClassContainingTheProperty.IsDraggingProperty, true);
       }
   }

   private void OnDragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
       DependencyObject source = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
       if(source != null)
       {
           source.SetParentValue<ListViewItem>(ClassContainingTheProperty.IsDraggingProperty, false);
       }
   }

   private void OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
       DependencyObject source = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
       if(source != null)
       {
           source.SetParentValue<ListViewItem>(ClassContainingTheProperty.IsDraggingProperty, false);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Use the Property in your Trigger

   ```
   <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
     <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="namespace:ClassContainingTheProperty.IsDragging" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
       </Trigger>
     </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   </ControlTemplate>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I've only ever seen drag-drop implemented with event handlers, so I think you're out of luck. I suggest you create your own dependency property to indicate a drag drop in progress.

Comment: The problem there is as I stated above, you can't just do an attached property because what would you attach it to?  I don't care about the object that's being dragged, rather the object it's being dragged over, so I'd have to attach that property on every control that can be dragged over, and actually it would be two properties... One to 'turn on' monitoring and another to report it.  I mean that can be done, but that seems like complete overkill.  Then again, it would work.  Still, they really should add that property to the control class hierarchy somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a real DragDrop event just watch for the DragOver event...

```
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DragOver">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color">
                        <ColorAnimation From="White" To="Black" Duration="0:0:1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
```